# Double Quotation marks for html classes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

When using Rubocop, they specify to use single quotation marks rather than double quotation in possible places other than interpolation. So what about the views of a rails app. The classes in the views are written as follows,

```
<div class="row-fluid">
</div>
```

Should this also be changed to single quotations? Do that have any performance change? I just want to know why does Rubocop prefer to use single quotation over double quotation.

Comment: Each language has its own conventions. Rubocop is based on the [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) which only applies to Ruby.

Comment: So what is your opinion for html views?

Comment: html is not Ruby.

Comment: @ShabiniRajadas I'm using double quotes in HTML, but the specification allows both, single quotes and double quotes. You can pick the one you like best.

Comment: The setting is configurable, single quotes just happens to be the default, for arbitrary reasons. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

1. Rubocop does not care about views.
2. HTML is not Ruby, thus it does not even make sense to follow Ruby conventions in HTML.

---

> Should this also be changed to single quotations?

Rubocop does not check views, so it's up to your preferences.

> I just want to know why does Rubocop prefer to use single quotation
> over double quotation.

[Today there is no performance difference](https://www.viget.com/articles/just-use-double-quoted-ruby-strings) when using single/double quotes.

I think it is just a matter of taste. I prefer to use single quotes if there is no need in double ones (interpolation). And it occurs to be the [opinion of the majority of active members of Ruby community](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).

Comment: So for views too? because the views are designed by the UI team. They usually give us designs with classes in Double quotations.

Comment: @ShabiniRajadas as I say: Rubocop does not check views, so it's line length, double quotes and so on should not necessarily follow the Ruby style conventions. Why? Because it is not even Ruby, it is html. So be calm when having double quotes in views.

Comment: @ShabiniRajadas _"the views are designed by the UI team"_ – then you should ask the UI team.

Comment: yes, I did ask them. But I wanted to know what happens when it is added to a rails app. So that's why asked for suggestions. If there is no significant difference in performance, then using any type of quotation is fine I guess.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyDeineko